# How to define function/macro so it is accesible throughout various cpp files

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++

I recently came across [this](http://www.utopiamechanicus.com/article/low-memory-serial-print/) nice `SerialPrint()` implementation:

```
void StreamPrint_progmem(Print &out,PGM_P format,...)
{
  // program memory version of printf - copy of format string and result share a buffer
  // so as to avoid too much memory use
  char formatString[128], *ptr;
  strncpy_P( formatString, format, sizeof(formatString) ); // copy in from program mem
  // null terminate - leave last char since we might need it in worst case for result's \0
  formatString[ sizeof(formatString)-2 ]='\0'; 
  ptr=&formatString[ strlen(formatString)+1 ]; // our result buffer...
  va_list args;
  va_start (args,format);
  vsnprintf(ptr, sizeof(formatString)-1-strlen(formatString), formatString, args );
  va_end (args);
  formatString[ sizeof(formatString)-1 ]='\0'; 
  out.print(ptr);
}

#define Serialprint(format, ...) StreamPrint_progmem(Serial,PSTR(format),##__VA_ARGS__)
#define Streamprint(stream,format, ...) StreamPrint_progmem(stream,PSTR(format),##__VA_ARGS__)
```

I want to use it in my more complex projects to save precious RAM space.

This works really well when I have just one *.ino file where I'm using the SerialPrint() function.
When I try to use it in my more complext projects, which consist of a central *.ino files and several *.cpp/*.h files (mostly one cpp/h pair per class).
The problem is if I put the code below into the *.ino file, it will not be known inside any of the *.cpp files. The compiler is not complanining, but I'm never seeing the serial output of my code.

Any ideas how to fix it?
I've tried putting this code in a central global.cpp/h file which I include everywhere, but it does not seem to work (no output on serial).

Thanks in advance!-

Comment: This looks to me like an inefficient emulation of [vsnprintf\_P()](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#ga2071feb5c92bf50a6bd508a07ead9515). Also, if you want to use printf-style formatting, why not just use `printf()`?

Comment: @EdgarBonet: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think the functions you mention are availabe in the arduino IDE. The code I linked to allows use of printf() like functionality with the added extra that it puts the formatting strings in progmem, saving precious RAM in the process.

Comment: They are available. On AVR-based boards, like the Uno, the Arduino library is built atop avr-libc, and all the functionality of this library is available. The only caveat is that you have to set up stdout before using it, c.f. the [documentation on stdio.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html). You can have the formatting string in progmem too by using `printf_P()` and the other _P variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought of turning it into a small library?

libraries/StreamPrint/StreamPrint.cpp:

```
#include <StreamPrint.h>

void StreamPrint_progmem(Print &out,PGM_P format,...)
{
  // program memory version of printf - copy of format string and result share a buffer
  // so as to avoid too much memory use
  char formatString[128], *ptr;
  strncpy_P( formatString, format, sizeof(formatString) ); // copy in from program mem
  // null terminate - leave last char since we might need it in worst case for result's \0
  formatString[ sizeof(formatString)-2 ]='\0'; 
  ptr=&formatString[ strlen(formatString)+1 ]; // our result buffer...
  va_list args;
  va_start (args,format);
  vsnprintf(ptr, sizeof(formatString)-1-strlen(formatString), formatString, args );
  va_end (args);
  formatString[ sizeof(formatString)-1 ]='\0'; 
  out.print(ptr);
}
```

libraries/StreamPrint/StreamPrint.h:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

extern void StreamPrint_progmem(Print &out,PGM_P format,...);

#define Serialprint(format, ...) StreamPrint_progmem(Serial,PSTR(format),##__VA_ARGS__)
#define Streamprint(stream,format, ...) StreamPrint_progmem(stream,PSTR(format),##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Then in your code, wherever you want to use it:

```
#include <StreamPrint.h>
```

You can read more about writing libraries here: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but got some compiler errors: `StreamPrint.h:6:68: error: initializer fails to determine size of '__c'`  `StreamPrint.h:6:68: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer`  `StreamPrint.h:6:94: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Print&' from an rvalue of type 'const char*'`  `StreamPrint.h:3:13: error: in passing argument 1 of 'void StreamPrint_progmem(Print&, const char*, ...)'`

Comment: Compiles fine for me. What are you using?

Comment: Normally visual studio 2013 with VisualMicro, but I tried in arduino IDE 1.6.1 and got the same error

Comment: It must be the code surrounding it then, since I can't get it to fail at all.  Try posting your test code.

Comment: Yep I had borked it... I started a new test sketch and suddenly everything works. Found out I had the code also still in my main *.ino file of my other big project.. Thanks for your help!